# Need to match ClockIn with Clock out, multiple clocks on same day SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join, database-cursor

I'm trying to get the clock in and clock out times to correspond to each other so that I can calculate hours worked/amount of breaks/time worked within working hours etc. I have a 'Clocking' table that looks like this:

MOCK DATA:

| Clock_ID | Employee_ID | Office | Clock_Date | Clock_Time | ActivityID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 06:43:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 55 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 06:45:00 | 1 |
| 3 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 07:00:00 | 1 |
| 4 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 07:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 75 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 07:05:00 | 1 |
| 6 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 10:59:00 | 2 |
| 7 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 11:50:00 | 1 |
| 8 | 55 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 12:18:00 | 2 |
| 9 | 55 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 12:30:00 | 1 |
| 10 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 13:03:00 | 2 |
| 11 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 13:04:00 | 2 |
| 12 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 13:39:00 | 1 |
| 13 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 13:39:00 | 1 |
| 14 | 75 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 15:59:00 | 2 |
| 15 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 16:00:00 | 2 |
| 16 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 16:00:00 | 2 |
| 17 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 16:00:00 | 2 |
| 18 | 55 | Pretoria CBD | 29/03/2022 | 16:00:00 | 2 |
| 19 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 06:46:00 | 1 |
| 20 | 55 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 06:51:00 | 1 |
| 21 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 06:54:00 | 1 |
| 22 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 06:54:00 | 1 |
| 23 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 11:24:00 | 2 |
| 24 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 12:11:00 | 1 |
| 25 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 13:03:00 | 2 |
| 26 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 14:10:00 | 1 |
| 27 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 16:01:00 | 2 |
| 28 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 16:01:00 | 2 |
| 29 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 16:01:00 | 2 |
| 30 | 55 | Pretoria CBD | 30/03/2022 | 16:05:00 | 2 |
| 31 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 06:48:00 | 1 |
| 32 | 55 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 06:53:00 | 1 |
| 33 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 06:55:00 | 1 |
| 34 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 07:09:00 | 1 |
| 35 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 12:02:00 | 2 |
| 36 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 12:09:00 | 1 |
| 37 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 12:34:00 | 2 |
| 38 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 12:34:00 | 2 |
| 39 | 83 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 13:09:00 | 1 |
| 40 | 80 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 13:09:00 | 1 |
| 41 | 55 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 13:32:00 | 2 |
| 42 | 54 | Pretoria CBD | 31/03/2022 | 15:56:00 | 2 |

The ActivityID determines whether it is a 'Clock IN' or 'Clock OUT'

I have used hash tables to separate the data into #clockIN and #clockOUT tables for any given Employee_ID as seen below:

**#ClockIN**

[image]

**#ClockOUT**

[image]

I tried using an inner join on the 'Clock_Date' on the tables to correspond clockINs to clockOUTs, but I get multiple clockOUTS for one clockIN due to the fact that employees can clockIN and OUT multiple times in a day: See below:

[image]

As you can see, the records are matched incorrectly, and a just joined on the date.

I cannot think of a way to correctly join them I.e ClockIn at 7:30 must be joined with the EARLIEST clock out on the same day and the next clockIN for that day must be the second earliest ClockIN which must be joined with the second earliest Clock OUT etc.

Would I have to use a cursor? if so, how could I implement that?

I will past all the SQL I used to get to this point.

```
Drop Table #ClockIn
Drop Table #ClockOut
DROP Table #SortedTimes
DROP Table #WorkBoundries

SELECT Clock_ID, Clock_Date AS Date, Clock_Time
    INTO #ClockIn 
    FROM Clocking
    WHERE Employee_ID = 82 AND ActivityID = 1
    SELECT * FROM #ClockIn

SELECT Clock_ID, Clock_Date AS Date, Clock_Time
    INTO #ClockOut 
    FROM Clocking
    WHERE Employee_ID = 82 AND ActivityID = 2
    SELECT * FROM #ClockOut
            
SELECT #ClockIn.Clock_Time As clockIN, #ClockOut.Clock_Time as ClockOUT, #ClockIn.Date INTO #SortedTimes
FROM #ClockIn
INNER JOIN #ClockOut On #ClockOut.Date = #ClockIN.Date
ORDER BY #ClockIn.Date ASC

SELECT * FROM #SortedTimes

SELECT MIN(clockIn)As TimeIn, MAX(ClockOUT) As TimeOut, [Date] As DayWorked INTO #WorkBoundries
FROM #SortedTimes
GROUP BY [Date]
SELECT * FROM #WorkBoundries
```

The #WorkBoundries is just to see if the person is clocking IN/OUT within their work hours or not.

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Sorry, Ill repost the question now

Comment: Hopefully [edit] rather than repost.

Comment: Yeah, just edited it now, only images of result tables now :)

Comment: If you re-read my original comments we want result tables as formatted text as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, images are not prefered. Why ? Because if we want to try something and we need testdata, than now with images we would have to type over all your data

Comment: I Added some 'Mock DATA' using a markdown table, all the other #Tables are calculated from that data using the sql provided. Hope that is a bit better xD

Comment: yes this is better, there are still images in your question but at least the data we need is not an image anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

```
select e.empid,
       e.clockdate,
       e.clocktime as starttime,
       o.clocktime as endtime
from   emp e
  outer apply (select top 1 e2.clocktime 
               from   emp e2 
               where  e2.empid = e.empid
               and    e2.activity = 2
               and    e2.clockdate = e.clockdate
               and    e2.clocktime > e.clocktime
               order by e2.clocktime
              ) o
where  e.activity = 1
order by e.empid, e.clocktime
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5c3a8446f929dd2c50d115ca030ce57) here

it results in this

| empid | clockdate | starttime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 2022-03-29 | 06:45:00.0000000 | 12:18:00.0000000 |
| 55 | 2022-03-29 | 12:30:00.0000000 | null |
| 83 | 2022-03-29 | 06:43:00.0000000 | 13:03:00.0000000 |
| 83 | 2022-03-29 | 13:39:00.0000000 | 16:00:00.0000000 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in **a single scan** of the base table, and no joins, by using window functions:

```sql
WITH NextValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      NextClockOut = LEAD(CASE WHEN c.ActivityID = 2 THEN c.Clock_Time END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY c.Office, c.Employee_ID, c.Clock_Date
             ORDER BY c.Clock_Time)
    FROM Clocking c
)
SELECT
  nv.Employee_ID,
  nv.Office,
  nv.Clock_Date,
  ClockIn = nv.Clock_Time,
  ClockOut = nv.NextClockOut
FROM NextValues nv
WHERE nv.ActivityID = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=792a00614af0c85a32018c070799498d)